# How can I initialize a form to appear in a different location than default without it appearing to move?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I'm having a heck of a time changing the default location of a form.

I tried to change it in the Form constructor, but my changes to the location get overwritten somehow. I even tried changing it on the form `Load` event, but no dice. Some other functionality of WinForms is overwriting the location I want with some default suggested location. And so far I know it happens after the `Load` event and after the constructor. The only success I've had is changing it on the form `Shown` event. But if I do this then sometimes (always if the form contains something like ReportViewer) you can see a flicker of the form appearing in the location WinForms wants to put it before it moves to the location I want it to go.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to set the form's [`StartPosition` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) to "Manual".** The other values (specifically, the default value of "WindowsDefaultLocation") will cause whatever position you specify to be overridden with a different value, just as you suspect. You can set this property either in the designer or through code in the form's constructor.

Then, just to make sure that you don't see any flickering, I'd set the form's [`Location` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx) in the constructor as well.

Also see: [Setting the Screen Location of Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420.aspx).

Finally, a word of caution: By manually specifying a form's location, you can run into trouble if your program is run by a user with an unexpected screen size or resolution, and/or with multiple monitors.

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm making my own form class linked to my new window manager. So, the first window appears at the default location but subsequent windows cascade relative to the window that opened them. I've got the best of both worlds. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @IsaacB: I don't know the details of your design, and it's possible you've already thought of this, but what you're recreating sounds an *awful* lot like an [MDI application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface). I don't buy into all the noise about how this is an "old" or "deprecated" presentational style—if it's the best fit for your specific application, you should use it. WinForms has built-in support for MDI applications, where the MDI child forms have most of the behavior you describe built-in.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, I'm a newbie. I didn't even know that option existed. I'm just flying by the seat of my pants here. I started out making just tabs. They will most likely use the tabs, but if the want to move a tab to its own window they can. Anyway, now that I've started on all this tab/windowing code its really hard to stop! :) Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @IsaacB: No problem. It's virtually impossible to learn all of the things offered by the .NET Framework or even WinForms at one go. And then, once you *think* you've got all of that, you'll start trying to learn the Windows API. It's like drinking from a firehose. And rolling your own solution isn't *all* bad—you're almost guaranteed to understand the code better when you get finished. Best of luck!

Comment: Furthermore, I just want to say that most of the time I really, really want the gui to behave a certain way I have to roll up my sleeves and code it myself. I've spent too many hours in the past searching for code someone else wrote to do what I want, and while sometimes I find the solution, it's sure up in the air whether it was more efficient to spend the time searching or coding. At least this way I'm learning things I guess.

Comment: Ugh, I've glanced at that windows API and I'm not looking forward to having to use it. I've already run into some situations where I must venture into it to solve a problem (such as how to change the flashing caret into a 'box' instead of the usual line (insert key)). Yikes. FYI I'm at about the 4 month mark using winforms.